# What is a student discussion place called?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there any English word for a place where students of different colleges discuss about  activities (events, reputation) of their colleges/universities?

Comment: Bar? Park? Dorm? Basement? Riverbank? You have to be more precise.

Comment: In above places are common not specfic to student and in dorm they may discuss other things. As in case of conference on specific topic where people discuss only about the agenda of conference

Comment: My point exactly: nothing prevents a conference from taking place in a bar or on a riverbank. Where does *your* conference take place?

Comment: Readers are understanding you to be asking the name for a space *permanently* assigned this function; are you perhaps asking what name you should give a space *temporarily* assigned it, eg for the duration of a conference?

Comment: It is a permanent place.

Comment: This sounds like you hav a particular phrase in _your_ native language for this concept. Also, it may be a concept specific to your university. Can you give an example? (link to a school website showing and talking about the example) Do you try google translate to at least give us a start? What is the phrase in your language? (ELU is not a translation service but giving us this info might help us)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "place" you are referring to a **building**, perhaps you're referring to the ***Student Union***.

Of course, just about anything can be "discussed" anywhere on a college campus, but the Student Union is often the "hub" of various extracurricular activities.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Students%27_union):

> In higher education, the student union is often accorded its own building on the campus, dedicated to social and organizational activities of the membership. In the United States, student union many times only refers to a physical building owned by the university with the purpose to provide services for students without a governing body also referred to as a student activity center.

The Wikipedia article also mentions that usage of the term "Student Union" varies widely from country to country, so that might not be an apt answer in some regions of the world.  I recommend reading through the article for more information.  But in the U.S.:

> In the U.S., the phrase "student union" often refers to a "student activity center" (also known as a "student center" or "student commons"), a building with dining halls, game rooms, lounges, student offices, and other spaces for student activities.

If by "place" you are referring to a **room**, that might be called any of the following:

- a meeting room
- a conference room
- a student lounge
- a general-purpose room

Which of those terms is most appropriate might depend on the furniture, and the arrangement of those furnishings.  It's hard to tell for certain, but I think ***student lounge*** might be the term you're after.

Comment: What if we have a physical room and we want to name that room where student meet and discuss college related activities

Comment: @Zia: I'd probably call that a _conference room_, a _meeting room_, or perhaps a _general-purpose room_, depending on its size, and the arrangement of the furniture.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: I agree if students were from the same college, but OP seems to want a word where students of *different* colleges meet. I don't think he means different colleges of the same university.

Comment: @bib: I initially interpreted the question as just that: students from different colleges within the same university (i.e., some locale that might answer, "Where are those studying liberal arts likely to meet with the engineers?"). But subsequent comments made me wonder if the OP is trying to organize a conference of some sort. It's hard to tell for sure what's being asked.

Comment: Yes I want student from different university to get together and talk. student lounge looks good but it would be better if i could find single word

Comment: @Zia: How big is this group? Do they all talk among themselves in small groups? Or listen to one main presenter? If it's a very large group all listening to one main speaker, that might be held in an _auditorium_. If it's not so many, divided into small subgroups, you could call that a _klatch_ (but that's more of a name for the gathering, as opposed to a name for the room itself). Problem is, each university might have a suitable room, but these venues wouldn't necessarily be called the same thing. It could be a _hall_, an _atrium_, a _theater_, or even a proper noun, like _The Cabot Room_.